# Memory leak in a multithreaded Java web server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, memory-leaks

I have a multithreaded Java web server that accepts requests from clients.

Each request in the RAM allocates memory for this request, but it is not cleared after the socket is closed. Cleanup occurs only after the web server is restarted.

If it is a memory leak, then in which part of the code can it occur?

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80)) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            while (true) {
                new Thread(new Client(socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;

    Client(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("run");
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Socket closed: " + socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the stack trace from the OutOfMemoyError and details of the version of Java and what platform you are running on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating threads in `while(true)` loop is never a good idea.
By default, each Thread created will allocate; 1mb for 64 bit jvm  and 128 kb for 32 bit jvm for its stack (this is for linux os, other details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/thread_basics.html)). Try `ExecutorService` for this kind of things. Threads are valuable resources.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a new thread for every incoming connection is INCREDIBLY inefficient and is probably what is leaking memory.

The correct approach is to use a thread pool with a fixed number of threads that are reused.

It's also worth pointing out that threads consume large amounts of native memory (off the Java heap) and very little on heap memory, so will not trigger garbage collection which in turn will call the finalizer to free up the native side.

EDIT:
Also the code doesn't do what you think it does. Having the accept outside the loop means that the code will just spin up threads for the same connection over and over agian, not a new thread for each connection.

Comment: While starting threads for every incoming connection is incredibly inefficient, it is not a memory leak. I had to check - I've just created and started a million threads but only held a reference to 100 of them using a size-limited collection, and no issues with out of memory whatsoever. (Laptop did get hot pretty quickly though) Completed threads get cleaned up by the garbage collector and do not leak memory by themselves.

Comment: Only if something else is driving GC, the code provided allocates only allocates Sockets (from accept) and new threads, if nothing else is allocating objects then nothing will trigger a GC which is needed to call the finalizer in to free the native component of the thread. Without seeing the actual OOM stack trace it's hard to say but I'm 90% sure this will be native memory exhaustion. I assume you did the test on the 64bit machine.

Comment: `LimitedLinkedHashMap<Thread, Boolean> threads = new LimitedLinkedHashMap<>(100); while (true) { Thread t = new Thread(); threads.put(t, Boolean.TRUE); t.start(); }` - yes on a 64bit machine but no Xmx setting; total memory usage remains constant at 245Mb. The only thing driving GC is thread allocation - there is nothing else that takes up memory.

Comment: Thank you. accept was inside the loop, I was mistaken when creating a question :)